# Data flow sink to csv not using file name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm starting to use the Dataflow preview from Data Factory, and one problem I'm having is doing a sink to delimited file on Blob Storage. I try to select the "Output to single file" option in settings, but when the dataflow runs, it generates a folder with a ID, and inside that folder a csv file is created with the pattern "part-0000-.csv", among with other files that I do not know the meaning of, not following the filename I inputed in settings.

How do I set the data flow to make the transformations and sink into a csv file on blob storage with a name pattern of my choosing??

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. The Blob Storage connection needs to have a folder specified in the destination, otherwise the sink creates a structure that ignores the filename specified in the settings.